# how to show multiple checkbox values from database in php

Tags: php, mysql

[Please see database's image also](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9epV.png)
I want to show my checkbox values from database.

```
Example : my value is 25,26.
So, How can i display it one by one ?
such as,
-- 1st value is : 25.
--2nd Value is : 26.
```

my code:

```
    $db = new mysqli("localhost","paroshic_paroshic","kxmcwQzLTrTR","paroshic_matri2018jl");
    $sql = "select * from tbldatingusermaster order by userid desc";
    $result = $db->query($sql);

    while($data = $result->fetch_object()){
    echo $data->education; //My value is 25,26
```

}

Thanks.

Comment: do you have code and something that you may have tried first?

Comment: What you're asking for is too broad and unclear. It would be beneficial for you to go over the help area if you haven't already https://stackoverflow.com/help and the related links inside it. Read through that and you'll see how things work here on Stack Overflow. It will give you a good idea as to how to formulate a good question, to see what can and should not be asked, as well as what is expected from you. This was made and put into place in order to help (you) have a better and positive experience here on Stack Overflow, which is what everybody wants and aims for.

Comment: I already upload my code..plzz check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write html tags to page with echo, you know that. So basicly it will be something like this:

```
while($data = $result->fetch_object()){
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="check" value="'.$data->educationid.'">'.$data->educationid.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: My value is 25,26 in database...i was insert it by checkbox....but i want to display it ....example [ my value is 25, my value is 26.

Answer (score 0):

I think the piece of the puzzle that you were looking for is perhaps `explode` to create an array of integers from the given string `$data->educationid` (ie: 25,26 )

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost","paroshic_paroshic","kxmcwQzLTrTR","paroshic_matri2018jl");
$sql = "select * from tbldatingusermaster order by userid desc";
$result = $db->query( $sql );

if( $result ){
    while( $data = $result->fetch_object() ){
        /* explode the string into little integers */
        $ids=explode( ',', $data->educationid );

        /* iterate through the pieces and generate an input[checkbox] element */
        foreach( $ids as $id )printf('<input type="checkbox" name="UNKNOWN[]" value="%s" />',$id);
    }
}
```